# Google Sheets pivot data with multiple values in one cell

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a pivot table but some cells have multiple options. How can I Take multiple values in one cell and making it so a pivot table can be run and count accordingly. Kindly see the table.

| Number | Contact Reasons |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Billing and Payments, Benefits |
| 2 | Processing Claims, Dental Services |
| 3 | Benefits |
| 4 | Billing and Pay |

I really appreciate your help.

Im trying to run a pivot table with correct number of occurrences.

Comment: What would be your desired output then?

Comment: You cannot.  you will have to rebuild your table (manually or formulaicly) before being able to pivot it.

Comment: Hi May I know the step that I should be doing first formulaicly? My desired output is pivot table where in it will count correctly count that 2 counts of Benefits, 2 counts of Billing and Payments, 2 counts of Benefits. Thanks. I prefer to formulate this since it will be easier for larger data. Thanks again

Comment: can anyone help pls? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,tocol(map(A2:A,lambda(x,split(x,", ",0))),3),Λ,unique(Σ),
     {Λ,index(countif(Σ,Λ))})
```

[image]